# JavaScript pass parameters error, the click event pass all parameters in the pass

Tags: javascript, events, parameters, arguments, pixi.js

I am making a game by js and pixi.js, I am having a trouble in pass parameters for function. The code below

```
newGame()
{
  // Some code before, then I get the audio which I want to play
  let audio = this.soundsArray[this.shuffleQuestionsInLevel[this.rightAnswer].sound];
    
  // Auto play audio at the begining of game
  this.playSound(audio);
  // Click to repeat the sound
  this.soundBtn.on('pointerdown', this.playSound.bind(this, audio));
}

// Play audio after 5 seconds
playSound(audio)
{  
  setTimeout(() => audio.play(), 5000);
}
```

At the first game, everything works perfectly, the exactly sound be played. However, from the second game, the click event `this.soundBtn.on('pointerdown', this.playSound.bind(this, audio));` play all the sound in the pass, it mean in the 2nd game, there are 2 sounds be played, in the 3rd game, there are 3 sounds be played.

The code to auto play audio at the begining `this.playSound(audio)` work well every time. Only sound in this game be played.

I do not know why I call the same function and pass the same parameter but only the code to auto play audio work. I want the click event work exactly like that. Anyone know what's the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are attaching the event handler when you start a game (when you call `newGame()`, but you are never detaching it:

```js
// This line attaches the handler, but it attaches a new handler everytime!
this.soundBtn.on('pointerdown', this.playSound.bind(this, audio));

// To understand why, let's write it more explicitly
//
// First a new "listener" function is created from this.playSound by calling bind
const listener = this.playSound.bind(this, audio);

// Then this function is attached as an event handler
this.soundBtn.on('pointerdown', listener);

// But since listener is not the same function as this.playSound anymore
// (because .bind produces a new function) the following line will not work
// and listener will stay attached
this.soundBtn.off('pointerdown', this.playSound);
```

In order to fix the problem you will most probably need to store the `listener` function somewhere so that you can detach it later:

```js
newGame() {
  // ...
  this.__playAudio = this.playAudio.bind(this, audio);
  this.soundBtn.on('pointerdown', this.__playAudio);
}

// And then when the game is over
this.soundBtn.off('pointerdown', this.__playAudio);
```

Or, if the `soundBtn` supports it, just detach all the `pointerdown` handlers when a game is over:

```js
this.soundBtn.off('pointerdown');
```

Comment: It works very well. Thank you so much, you saved my college career ^^!

Comment: Hehe glad to have helped :)